# What email does Azure send account level alerts to

Tags: azure

As an example, they recently automatically migrated a SendGrid account to a new resource type, and it broke our app. I assume they must have sent some emails warning us before hand but I never received anything. I am a subscription owner, but just a regular member in Azure AD.

Comment: not really. SendGrid is a separate service provided by 3rd party company.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Do you mean you don't think I would have gotten an email alert about this breaking change?